# NameError: uninitialized constant className

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting error in irb

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Student
```

for `Student.new` or whatever model operations are there.

But in rails it gives no error and it works fine. What would be the reason?

This error only happens in Windows, same code I have in Linux and there it works fine.

What makes the difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

irb has nothing to do with your rails project.

What you want instead is to run

```
rails console
```

from within your rails project directory. Here you have access to everything defined within the application - Rails loads everything automatically.

Comment: To expand a bit, rails will automatically load everything under app.  irb won't load anything.  You'd need to load it yourself.

Comment: @InQusitive not at all :)

Answer (score 0):

rails c

Create new tab in terminal. Here you may work with modals. Like CRUD operations.

But make sure your terminal must pointing in rails working directory before trying rails c command ...